# Fill in the blank question about meaning of estimate

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Fill in the blank with proper answer
>   We cannot ......... that our flights will never be delayed.
>
> 1. spend
> 2. estimate
> 3. follow
> 4. create

I think the answer is "estimate" but in the book in which I found this question, the answer is "spend". It said that in this question, it means guarantee (or assure). I think it doesn't make any sense. So, what is the right answer? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word spend does not mean "guarantee" or "assure" in modern English, and I can find no dictionary referring to this as an obsolete meaning.

The book is wrong. None of the suggested words would be appropriate in the gap for a reasonable meaning.

Comment: I agree. However, I will add that if I were forced to pick one of the options, 2. seems the least wrong to me. (Just because it is at least closest in meaning to "guarantee." But the book is certainly in error.